# Help with UI or a web application

Tags: web-applications

I am working on a web app but am not a UI designer. I have a bare bones site working but before releasing the product I would like to make it look a little professional. What are the things I should do? Here is the list I came up with. Can I get(buy) any of these from sites out there?

- Logo
- Font
- CSS (layout) with a color scheme.

I am also new to web development. Learned the whole html/js/css before doing this.

The site itself is a web based game and so there is a login page, about page, page describing the game and the actual game page itself. What I am trying to get at is, I hope this is the way people go about working on projects. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

-P

Comment: No offense, but I think you may be farther away from releasing than you think you are ...

Comment: Sure. I definitely think so too. I wanted to integrate the actual UI and start testing and fine tuning rather than completely wrapping it up and then thinking about fonts and colors.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you try to buy a design?

You can certainly contact a design firm and pay for someone to design it for you.

As the developer, you should probably put on your waders and get involved ASAP...

Here are a few ways to start:

Have one of your testers (if you don't have testers or buddies, then it's on you) go through and decide what they think it should look like.  Have them just draw it on paper, gimp, photochop, mspaint, whatever.

Since you are a developer - use that drawing to decide the logical grouping of elements.  Do you have a navigation ribbon?  Do you think it looks more intuitive on the left side or above the top?  etc

Revisit your code - do you need to add id's to objects?  At minimum, classes would be good.

Lastly, go dig into CSS.  If you can't achieve what you want in CSS then jump to jquery.

It's easy to say "I'm a developer - not a designer" and try to skip this step... unfortunately, that excuse isn't going to work forever. ;)

Comment: Designing website isn't about learning css. You might know every single css selector and style attribute. You might also know all the HTML tags, but when you have zero feeling for how should things look, than you won't ever make good design.

Comment: I am not saying that you can't learn it, but it's not that simple. Also saying "I'm a developer, not designer." is 100% acceptable point of view. You don't have to be a jack-of-all-trades and if you become one you won't ever beat 'specialization' unless you are really exceptionally gifted.

Comment: I want to be clear that I didn't mean designers don't have their own value.  Even bad design is design - OP should suck it up and do his best, revisit the design later if necessary.  Besides, there is no better way to learn the value of good practice (that is, adding IDs where appropriate and how classes should be structured - this is generally not important in most web apps but CRUCIAL to good design).

Comment: I also agree to disagree on the "not a designer - 100% acceptable view" part.  You certainly don't have to master design, but whoever you are... if you try to demo a flawlessly functional piece of code and no one understands what it does because it isn't intuitive and just prints numbers in a console.... you can certainly shrug your shoulders and say "I'm not a designer."  You certainly won't achieve the results you wanted and most of your work will be completely overlooked. ;)  Even basic design is still design.

Comment: I am not going to argue here... we don't know OP enough and don't know the whole context (at least I don't). But I just wanted to avoid more websites like [this](http://kobl.host.sk/index.kobl.htm) or [this](http://www.centex.net/~elliott/unicorn.html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I definitely know exactly what the flow of pages and look and feel looks like. I just am really bad at picking colors and fonts and of course creating logos. That is what I am more concerned about. Buying the CSS idea is more for the colors and fonts rather than the UI design itself. I would drop the whole thing than put out something like dampe suggested :). Instead I would make it plaintext if nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Go spend tiny amount of cash and buy pre-made templates at [**themeforest**](http://themeforest.net/).
Or, if you want to spend MUCH more, but get your unique design and everything you want, go to [**99designs**](http://99designs.com/).

Themeforest is acually part of big marketplace... you can also visit their another marketplaces for other stuff (like graphic assets, sounds etc.)

**If you want to invest time** and learn it, then just google for web design blogs and portals. But there is list of my favs:

[Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/)
[NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/)
[webdesigner wall](http://webdesignerwall.com/)